# Uninstalled app reappears after boot

Tags: factory-reset, uninstallation

I have a problematic LG P715 which keeps randomly rebooting every few seconds after boot, and I'd like to remove some sensitive data before sending it to a random technician.

I cannot factory erase it (usually it reboots before I can reach the button, but even when it does reach it, after confirming that I want to erase, it simply does nothing), so I tried uninstalling each application individually to at least progress somewhat.

I was able to go to Setttings -> Applications, choose some applications, click on Uninstall, then confirm, wait for it to finish uninstalling, then click Ok, then return to the phone. Even after doing all that, after rebooting the phone, the same applications still appear on the list of Downloaded applications.

I wonder, how is this possible? They had disappeared from the list before reboot. Are they never actually erased after uninstallation? Is there something I can do to force them to be erased?

**Edit**: It's actually worse than I thought: I managed to get an ADB shell (no root) for a few seconds, so I deleted some files in the sdcard folder (where I had permission) via `rm` inside the ADB shell, but again after rebooting all those files and directories were there. It seems there must be some issue between some temporary storage and the permanent one, but I am at a loss to what happens in there, how can these commands execute and seem to produce some result when they actually do nothing.

Comment: Try to use the volume button combination to factory reset it before the android system itself boots up.

Comment: I tried what I found in several sites, one of them leads to an "Emergency mode !!" yellow screen that seems written by a 4-year old, the others lead to some partial reset where it asks my settings again (time zone, language), but after that it reboots back into the previous configuration with everything as before the attempted reset.

Comment: Also, it is so buggy that it actually seems to reboot while doing the factory reset: the green android animation with the geometrical shape in its belly only appears for a couple seconds, before the phone reboots. So I gave up on that, but what I'm really curious about is how it manages to claim the application has been uninstalled but afterwards it comes back from nowhere.